# I am stuck when pressing the key OK in a UIAlertAction

Tags: ios, swift, uialertaction

I am quite new to Swift and IOS, but I don't think that I should be stuck in the alert "popup". I can see the following but when pressing Restart, nothing happens.[Alert popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ebpp.png)

If I use a closure instead of nil to handler nothing happened.

I wrote the following in Swift5 using Xcode 10.3:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, 
           preferredStyle: .alert)

let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default, handler: nil)    
alert.addAction(action)
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Instead of showing the code that works, show the code that is causing your issue. And clearly explain what is happening exactly.

Comment: @imilejo, please add handler completion also so that it would help to know the exact issue.

Comment: The problem is that when the alert message is presented, the program hangs

Answer (score -1):

You need to dismiss the alert inside the completion handler of the ok action.

Comment: No, you do not. The action handler is not called until the alert has already been dismissed.